# How to call a python get method from the web browser

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python method which is part of a query, that takes a url and uses part of the url to run a query and send the output.

```
@app.route('/status/<string:task_id>', methods=['GET'])
def test(task_id):
  if task_id == "test":
    def test_method(task_id):
      result = query_db(query .format(task_id))
      data = json.dumps(result)
      resp = Response(json_converter(data), status=200, mimetype='application/json')
      return resp
  else:
    return jsonify({"result":"unknown", "reason":"invalid {0} url " .format(task_id)})
```

when I run

```
http://<ip address>/status/test
```

I get a "This site can’t be reached", but instead of a variable in the app.route, if I use a real value, it works fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you have that nested function. You don't need it; it the value is "test", you want to return the response directly.

Remove the line `def test_method(task_id)` and indent the following lines appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

When `task_id` is `test`, nothing is returned.

You want to return a call to `test_method` if the branch condition is matched.